# Automatically login when clicking on a URL and redirect to given URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I can't find anything specific. I'm new to ASP.NET, and C# at the same time... so I'm struggling to get it right...

I have User form submission URL, when I click this URL I get to the login page (session use), but how to automatically login when clicking the URL without having to go through the login page ?

Answer (score 1):

if I I understand correctly
You can make direct authentication with username and password you want something like

In your pageLoad add this:

```
FormsAuthentication.Authenticate("yourUser", "yourPass");
```